# How to read Editable combo box in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make combobox as editable.

The combobox is having Data binding, which gets updated with list of names from Database.
If desired name is not present in the list, user can enter new name using this combobox (IsEditable is set to true).

Also, there is some record in the database for previously project, which I want to display based upon project selection, which user want to update.

Here is XAML code

Based on TPTypeComboBox selection

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="285,68,0,0" Name="TPTypeComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectionChanged="TPTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Code to update ProjectIDUsedComboBox

```
    private void TPTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectIDUsedComboTxtBox.DataContext = DBConnector.IsTPRecordsExists();     // ISTPRecordsEsixts returns DataTable 
    }
```

Here is XAML code   (for editable combobox)

```
<ComboBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="131,144,0,0" Name="ProjectIDUsedComboTxtBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="271" IsEditable="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="project_name_used" SelectionChanged="ProjectIDUsedComboTxtBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

Now I want to read the new entered value from the text entered.

Now on a Update button click, I am trying to read value from editable combo box.

```
<Button Content="Update" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,596,0,0" Name="UpdateTPRecordButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Click="UpdateTPRecordButton_Click" />
```

First I am trying to read the selected value, if its null, then I am trying to read from the text.

```
if (ProjectIDUsedComboTxtBox != null)
{
    var selItem = (DataRowView)ProjectIDUsedComboTxtBox.SelectedItem;
    if (selItem != null)
        {
            var temp = selItem.Row;                
            var value = (string)temp.ItemArray.GetValue(0);
        }
        else
        {
            var prjIDUsed = ProjectIDUsedComboTxtBox.Text.Trim();
        }           
}
```

But I am getting 'ProjectIDUsedComboTxtBox' as null always.

Any suggestion/link, how to read this text value.

Regards

Comment: You should be using [x:Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx) to expose that element to code behind, not Name.

Comment: Is your reading code in the SelectionChanged handler or is it in another handler?

Comment: I am reading it in another handler (button click)

Comment: Your code seems to work perfectly. Can you post more details (or more code) please?

Comment: @Il Vic, edited question.

Comment: is 'ProjectIDUsedComboTxtBox' declared in a template ?, if so show us template

Comment: I am sorry, I can't find anything wrong in your code. The ComboBox `Text` property should contain the text entered by the user.

Comment: @Muds, No its not declared in a template.

Comment: I got the mistake I was making, ProjectIDUsedComboTxtBox is getting reset to NULL in one of the function where all texts in textbox controls is getting cleared.